# How to fix ISNULL fuction

Tags: sql

I have a table where it shows all the names and credit limit.

I have to use `isnull` function to display ('Pending')

where people who do not have credit limit aka (Null).

When I tried, it gave me an error `'Error converting data type varchar to numeric.'`

```
select concat('Welcome back, ' + CustomerName, '.' , ' Your credit limit is: ', CreditLimit, isnull(CreditLimit,'('Pending'))) from [Sales].[Customers]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ISNULL will expect the second attribute to have the same type as the first, and will try to convert it. Since the CreditLimit is a number, the database will try to cast the varchar/string '(Pending)' to a number too, which fails.

The solution: Cast CreditLimit to a string type. After all, it's going to be part of a sentence anyway, and you don't need it as a number at that point.

The cast would work something like this, but it may depend on the database you're using, which wasn't specified. `STR` at least works for SQL Server, which your query looks like. Other databases, might use functions like `CAST` or `CONVERT`, which are bit more generic and will require you to specify the type.

```
ISNULL(STR(CreditLimit), '(Pending)')
```

Comment: It's because you also have CreditLimit before the `IsNull` call. That one is obsolete. `IsNull` will return either `STR(CreditLimit)`, or the `(Pending)`, if the number is null.

Comment: ISNULL(STR(CreditLimit), '(Pending)') I have not learned STR yet, so I dont think I can use that!

Comment: Got it! THANKS a TON

Comment: You learned it now, right? Or if you have learned about any other way of converting, you could use that. You can probably even force it using a concatenation of a string and a number, although I think that's a bit ugly: `IsNull(''||CreditLimit, '(Pending)')`. Long story short, you have to make that number into a string, _somehow_. :)